# Docker Container Mount Folder

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-machine

I am trying to mount my VM Machine folder to Container using below command

```
sudo docker run -d -it  --name devtest \
-v /home/minhaj/GOQTINDOOR:/home/user:Z  therecipe/qt:linux bash
```

But do not see any folder on my Container home/user. Please advise what is wrong in my command or do I need to execute more commands to mount folder on Container.

Comment: Where are you running this command? The machine which hosts docker or outside the VM?

Comment: I am running this command in Terminal, outside of Container... Host is Ubuntu & it hosts Docker as well.
The command executed successfully but it is not showing folder in Container.

Comment: The command is correct as such. What is the output of `sudo docker run -d -it  --name devtest \
-v /home/minhaj/GOQTINDOOR:/home/user:Z  -w /home/user therecipe/qt:linux bash -c "pwd && ls -alh"`

Comment: @TarunLalwani after execution command getting below result

`minhaj@minhaj-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ sudo docker run -d -it  --name devtest -v /home/minhaj/GOQTINDOOR:/home/user  therecipe/qt:linux bash 
2192715a3c9d1d4e47f901a40661e21ebdc85d23d68cc05bc15077e74575cc12`

Comment: My bad please remove the `-d` flag and then try again

Comment: @TarunLalwani thanks its fixed! I was running Container in detached mode...

Comment: @TarunLalwani please advise how to remove mounted folder only...

Comment: What do you mean by remove mounted folder only?

Comment: remove this new container devtest,

Comment: @TarunLalwani, I have compiled source code & generated an output file into Container, please advise how can I copy this output file into Virtual Machine?

Comment: docker cp is used to cp data from Container to VM. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are running the container in detached mode. Remove `-d`

```
sudo docker run -it --name devtest -v /home/minhaj/GOQTINDOOR:/home/user therecipe/qt:linux bash​
```

After this if you compile something inside the container and copy it is inside the `/home/user` folder it will be automatically available inside `/home/minhaj/GOQTINDOOR`. You can copy and delete any file inside `/home/minhaj/GOQTINDOOR`. But you can't delete the `/home/minhaj/GOQTINDOOR` folder itself as it the mount point.

Any files or folder inside `/home/minhaj/GOQTINDOOR` can be deleted from inside the container by delete them from `/home/user` folder.

`docker cp` command is only required if you want to copy a file which is not there in any mounted path.

For that you can use

```
docker cp <containerid>:<pathinsidecontainer> <pathonhost>
```